# Onde encontro a DLL microsoft.expression.encoder.devices?

Tags: c#, dll, referência

Estou tentando desenvolver um afinador de instrumentos de cordas em C#. Encontrei um projeto chamado [FFT Guitar Tunner](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32172/FFT-Guitar-Tuner), mas estive tendo alguns problemas com as referências dele. No fim de tudo a única referência que continua dando problema é:
`microsoft.expression.encoder.devices`

Já baixei o Microsoft Encorder 4 mas não encontrei esta DLL. Não a encontrei em nenhum outro lugar.

Comment: Você já leu este link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996897/c-sharp-microsoft-expression-encoder-missing-reference-how-to-add-them-to-pro

Comment: Achei este informação. Para o Namespace  Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.Devices o Assembly é microsoft.expression.encoder.dll (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.encoder.devices.encoderdevice%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)

Comment: Esta dica parece interessante: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/223832/Reference-to-Microsoft-Expression-Encoder

Comment: O link da MSDN confirmando o namespace eu já tinha visto sim, e já tinha instalado o Microsoft encorder 4 também, porém o caminho que indicaram nas respostas que você me deu estava vazio, estou desinstalando e baixando novamente para ver se dessa vez funciona. Voltarei aqui se alguma mudança ocorra.

Answer (score 1):

Olha não posso te ajudar muito em relação as dependencias!

Posso te dar umas dicas, eu não sei a fundo quais são as especificações necessárias para o seu projeto e muito menos sobre o projeto chamado FFT Guitar tunner, acho que foi você que abriu um tópico sobre como reconhecer frequências a um tempinho, mas definitivamente utilizar FFT para construir afinadores não é considerado uma boa prática, veja bem eu disse "considerado", mas se for insistir com FFT, para conseguir realmente uma boa precisão é necessário que seje utilizado algumas técnicas em paralelo como zero padd, computar a diferença entre as fases[1] e por fim efetuar    interpolação parabólica ao redor do componente espectral encontrado pela FFT, trabalhar no domínio da frequência dá muito trabalho computacional ainda mais se o seu projeto for em tempo real, existem alternativas mais simples no domínio do tempo, encontrar frequências com uma simples autocorrelação pode ser simples e extremamente rápido e permite aplicações em tempo real, se for só trabalhar com afinação de guitarra você pode utilizar filtros(passa-altas, passa-baixa) para remover frequências espúrias e garantir um melhor resultado ...

Mais um ponto importante, quando falamos de frequência isso é definido como sendo a quantidade de vezes que um determinado ciclo se repete ou seja a sua periodicidade, no caso de um acorde de guitarra soando o que você escuta ou seja a sensação do timbre que você escuta pode ser totalmente diferente da frequência encontrada utilizando somente FFT, ou seja é a diferença entre a percepção do som que você realmente escuta com a oscilação física da forma de onda.

[1] J. L. Flanagan and R. M. Golden, “Phase vocoder,” Bell Systems Technical Journal, vol. 45, pp. 1493–1509, 1966.